# Proof $(g,x) \mapsto x * g^{-1}$ is a left group action.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I am getting a bit confused with group actions. I have to prove that the map $(g,x)\mapsto x*g^{-1}$ is a **left** group action. I have already proven it to be a group action using the fact that it is associative, and there is an identity element. How do I go about proving that it is a **left** group action? Any ideas?

Comment: Are the operations in $g\circ x \mapsto x * g^{-1}$,  $\circ$ and $*$ the same?

Comment: sorry the operation should be: $ (g,x) \mapsto x*g^{-1} $

Comment: HInt: $(gh)^{-1}=h^{-1}g^{-1}$.

Comment: With reference to left-cancellation law, I state that this left-action is a *property of an element*, that is in the group

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, thenthe answer is simple.  It is a left group action because it is a group action in which the $g$ is on the left of the $x$. A left group action of a group $G$ on a set $X$  is a map $G \times X \to X$, and a right group action is a map $X \times G \to X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us write an action as a function $A:G\times X \to X$.
Then, for $A$ to be a left action, it has to satisfy $A(g, A(h, x)) = A(gh, x)$.
In contrast, right actions satisfy $A(g, A(h,x)) = A(hg, x)$.
(In fact, right actions are usually written as $B:X\times G\to X$ satisfying $H(H(x, g), h) = H(x, gh)$ to make it looks more like an associativity law.

So for your question, you need to show:

> $A(g, A(h,x)) = A(g, x*h^{-1}) = x*h^{-1}*g^{-1} = x*(gh)^{-1} = A(gh, x)$
>  So even if the $g$ 'appears' on the right, it is indeed a left action.

Answer (score 4):

*If $x*g$ is a (right) action* ("$hyp.$"), then $g\cdot x := x*g^{-1}$ is a left action. In fact:

1. $\space\space e\cdot x=x*e^{-1}=x*e\stackrel{hyp.}{=}x, \space\forall x\in X$;
2. \begin{alignat}{1}
   (gh)\cdot x &= x * (gh)^{-1} \\
   &= x*(h^{-1}g^{-1}) \\
   &\stackrel{hyp.}{=} (x*h^{-1})*g^{-1} \\
   &= g\cdot (x*h^{-1}) \\
   &= g\cdot (h\cdot x) \\
   \end{alignat}

Answer (score 0):

> [image]

Here, our mapping takes a ordered set from the cartesian product $G\  * \ X$ to an element in set $X$, $(g,x):=xg^{-1}$

> [image]

If we let the mapping $(g,x)\mapsto x*g^{-1}$ be a left group action of G on S.

Then, by that very assumption, we can **now** say that the mapping **must** satisfy the axioms of the left group actions.

P.S. If your mapping satisfies the axioms of the left group actions, *it implies* that

[image]

Comment: Hm I think I am making it a bit more difficult than it should be, but is it something like this:
$(g,x)=(h,x) \implies xg^{-1}=xh^{-1} \implies g^{-1}=h^{-1} \implies g=h \implies gx=hx$ ?

Comment: No, It cannot be approached like the left cancellation proof. The more i read the definition of the left group action, the more I agree on this.

Comment: @Josephine What are the sets G and S given to you?

Comment: what do you mean? I just know that G is a group and X is a general collection of things, nothing specific. I guess they just want me to think about the definition of left group actions and make me realize that $ gx:= xg^{-1} $, but I am having a hard time seeing it

Comment: @Josephine don't worry, this "seeing" need not be visual seeing like looking at the mountains but axiomatic-application seeing like a disproving reasoning. Carrying on, so G is a group and S (here X) is a set and the mapping(rule) is that $gx:= xg^{-1}$.

Comment: I am adding one more definition to my answer

Comment: @Josephine, when you go on to support with reasonings that the mapping would satisfy compatibility axioms, you would pick up #ancientmathematics answers too.